# Comments in Python MANIFEST.in

Tags: python, manifest, distutils

Is there any way to comment some line in the manifest file used by Python? If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comments start with the hash character: `#`; a comment lasts to the end of the line. See an example at [PyPA sample project](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/3a836905fbd687af334db16b16c37cf51dcbc99c/MANIFEST.in).

Comment: The link to `MANIFEST.in` no longer works (recently been removed). You can access it in the last stage [here](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/3a836905fbd687af334db16b16c37cf51dcbc99c/MANIFEST.in)